# PySpark: How to specify column with comma as decimal

Tags: csv, pyspark, number-formatting

I am working with PySpark and loading a `csv` file. I have a column with numbers in European format, which means that comma replaces the dot and vice versa.

For example: I have `2.416,67` instead of `2,416.67`.

```
My data in .csv file looks like this -    
ID;    Revenue
21;    2.645,45
23;   31.147,05
.
.
55;    1.009,11
```

In pandas, such a file can easily be read by specifying `decimal=','` and `thousands='.'` options inside `pd.read_csv()` to read European formats.

**Pandas code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("filepath/revenues.csv",sep=';',decimal=',',thousands='.')
```

I don't know how can this be done in PySpark.

**PySpark code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType, StringType
schema = StructType([
            StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
            StructField("Revenue", FloatType(), True)
                    ])
df=spark.read.csv("filepath/revenues.csv",sep=';',encoding='UTF-8', schema=schema, header=True)
```

Can anyone suggest as to how we can load such a file in PySpark using the above mentioned `.csv()` function?

Comment: Why are you specifying a semicolon separator? The sample file you provided looks to be whitespace-delimited, probably with tabs?

Comment: That was just an example. Ok, let me change it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You won't be able to read it as a float because the format of the data.  You need to read it as a string, clean it up and then cast to float:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

df = spark.read.option("headers", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("my_csv.csv", sep=";")
df = df.withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace('revenue', '\\.', ''))
df = df.withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace('revenue', ',', '.'))
df = df.withColumn('revenue', df['revenue'].cast("float"))
```

You can probably just chain these all together too:

```
df = spark.read.option("headers", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("my_csv.csv", sep=";")
df = (
         df
         .withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace('revenue', '\\.', ''))
         .withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace('revenue', ',', '.'))
         .withColumn('revenue', df['revenue'].cast("float"))
     )
```

Please note this I haven't tested this so there may be a typo or two in there.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response. Well, I was thinking about it as well, but I thought that may be there is a function to do that. I will search for it and in case I don't find a one, then I will add it as an answer.

Comment: AFAIK There isn't a function to do it using only the `.csv()` method. Why do you have this as a requirement?

Comment: Hi, well, I do not have such a requirement. Just wanted to use an inbuilt function if there is a one. But, yes, regex with replace is good enough :)

Comment: Did this address your issue? If so can the question closed?

Comment: Hi Sir, The code you have provided makes complete sense and I am 99% sure that it will work. I am having some problems with my system and once my system is running, I will test your code and would mark it as answer. Hope it's ok. Latest by tomorrow. Once again, thank you so much for your help. It's always appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Best wishes.

Comment: Hi jhole89, just replace '.' with '\\.' in the first regex expression, as DOT matches everything in Regex and change FloatType to "float" for this code to work. Other than this, the code works perfectly.

Comment: Notes: We need to escape . to match it literally, as . is a special character that matches almost any character in regex. That's why we use '\\.' instead of mere '.'.

Comment: You van write it a bit more compact:
`df = df.withColumn('revenue', regexp_replace(regexp_replace('revenue', '\\.', ''), ',', '.').cast("float")`

Answer (score 1):

*If your dataset has lots of float columns, but the size of the dataset is still small enough to preprocess it first with pandas*, I found it easier to just do the following.

```
import pandas as pd

df_pandas = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', sep=';', decimal=',')
df_pandas.to_csv('yourfile__dot_as_decimal_separator.csv', sep=';', decimal='.') # optionally also header=True of course.

df_spark = spark.csv.read('yourfile__dot_as_decimal_separator.csv', sep=';', inferSchema=True) # optionally also header=True of course.
```

I did find jhole89's answer very useful, but found it a pain to apply it on a dataset with a lot of columns (multiple hundreds).

I mean:

- manually specifying float columns and converting them is a lot of effort,
- trying to find them dynamically by checking which columns are string-typed and contain a comma, avoiding that datetime columns with millesecond separators aren't taken into account etc., casting to float that fails on certain columns because they are text containing comma's but aren't intended to be parsed as float numbers: this causes headaches.

Therefore, *if* there are multiple float columns *and* your dataset can be preprocessed with pandas, you can apply the above code.

Answer (score -1):

**Make sure your SQL table is pre-formatted to read NUMERIC instead of INTEGER.** I had a big trouble trying to figure out all about encoding and the different formats of dots and commas and etc. and in the end the problem was much more primitive, it was pre-formatted to read only INTEGER numbers, and therefore no decimals would ever be accepted, no matter if with commas or dots. Then I just had to change my SQL table to accept real numbers (NUMERIC) instead and that was it.

Comment: Please post some code to motivate your answer. Till date, after discussing with many people, I haven't found any way to import numbers in `European/German` format in `PySpark`. The answer provided by @jhole89 was what most people did. If you have found a way, demonstrate that by posting the requisite code. Many thanks.

Comment: my table looked something like this:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.ECOSTAT (
  DEST CHAR(50),
  AIRLINE CHAR(50),
  SHP_WEIGHT INTEGER
);
And I was trying to import data for SHP_WEIGHT with the following formats: 122.5, 2500.5, 750.3 (this is an English format, dots instead of commas).
And the problem was not that I had a German server, but how I create the table. I have create the variable SHP_WEIGHT as INTEGER, and integers don't take decimal numbers. So then I've modified the table and recreated the SHP_WEIGHT NUMERIC (which accepts real numbers like 122.5) and it worked!

Comment: I think you are totally missing the point. To refer to your example, my data will be something like 122,4; 2500,5; 750,3. There is no DataType in PySpark, which can handle this - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html We has to import this as String in the Schema and then convert to proper British format and then cast as float/int. That’s what @jhole89 is suggesting in his answer. Thanks you for your efforts.