# Convert string price value to double type in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a requirement to convert the price value to german number format. But, I have used `regexp_replace` function in pyspark and handled the way to change. But, the output type it is returning is **StringType** and we have to cast it to **DoubleType**. When performing casting the output values are updating as **null** values

Sample dataframe input:

```
|price_num|
|3,104.15 |
|4,534.56 |
```

I'm using dataframe select to create a new column:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(format_number( -1 * col('price_num').cast('double'), 2), '\\.', '@'), ',', '\\.'), '@', ',').alias(german_format)
```

I need to cast the value in doubleType..Please suggest any way to cast and not the populate null values.

Output without casting:

```
price_num|german_format
string   |string
3,104.15 |-3.104,15
4,534.56 |-4.534,56
```

My output when casting:

```
price_num|german_format
string   |double
3,104.15 |null
4,534.56 |null   #Invalid values
```

Expected output:

```
price_num|german_format
string   |double
3,104.15 |-3.104,15
4,534.56 |-4.534,56
```

Comment: Well, you can't cast to `double` when `string` is in German format. PySpark doesn't allow it. Casting operations have to de done in American/British format and not in European ones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702608/pyspark-how-to-specify-column-with-comma-as-decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to remove the dots from the European string number format of the price and replace the comma by a dot. Then you can cast it to double type.

Try this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("-3.104,15",), ("-3.104,15",)], ['price_european_format'])

df.withColumn("price_double", regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
    col("price_european_format"), '\\.', ''), ',', '\\.').cast("double"))\
  .show()
```

Gives:

```
+---------------------+------------+
|price_european_format|price_double|
+---------------------+------------+
|            -3.104,15|    -3104.15|
|            -3.104,15|    -3104.15|
+---------------------+------------+
```